# Controller is returning a blank data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

the controller is returning a blank data/view and I think something is wrong with my routes. if I remove `{locale}`, the data is retrieved.

Can anyone help with returning the data properly while my routes have `{locale}` in it? Here are my related code:

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('{locale}/projects/{id}/billings', 'ProjectController@showbilling')
     ->name('showbilling');
Route::post('{locale}/projects/{id}', 'ProjectController@addbilling')
     ->name('addbilling');
```

**ProjectController.php**

```
public function showbilling($id)
{
    $billings = Project::find($id);
    $locale = app()->getLocale();

    return $billings;
    //return view('admin.addbillings', compact('billings'));
}
```

Edit: Here's my full web.php

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return redirect(app()->getLocale());
});



Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 'middleware' => 'setlocale'], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {

    return view('welcome');
    })->name('main');

    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

    //Customers
    Route::get('/customers', 'CustomerController@showcust')->name('customers');
    Route::post('/sendcust', 'CustomerController@sendcust')->name('sendcust');


    //Items
    Route::get('/items', 'ItemController@showitems')->name('items');
    Route::post('/senditem', 'ItemController@senditem')->name('senditem');

    //Projects
    Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectController@showprojects')->name('projects');
    Route::post('/sendproj', 'ProjectController@sendproj')->name('sendproj');
    //ProjectBillings
    Route::get('/projects/{id}/billings', 'ProjectController@showbilling')->name('showbilling');
    Route::post('/projects/{id}', 'ProjectController@addbilling')->name('addbilling');  

    //Invoices
    Route::get('/invoices', 'InvoiceController@showinvoice')->name('invoices');
    Route::post('/sendinvoitem', 'InvoiceController@sendinvoitem')->name('sendinvoitem');
    Route::get('/invoices/{id}/details', 'InvoiceController@showdetails');
    Route::post('/updateitem','InvoiceController@updatedetail')->name('updateitem');
    Route::get('invoices/{id}/generate', 'InvoiceController@generate');
    Route::post('/updatestatus', 'InvoiceController@changestatus')->name('updatestatus');

});
```

Comment: Where is locale being ingested?  You don't seem to have a method parameter for it.

Comment: As Devon said, what is the purpose of `$locale` there?

Comment: gonna comment my full web.php.

Comment: updated question. kindly read again thanks. :)

Comment: HCK, the purpose of {locale} is for localization

Comment: Does it work if you update the methods to `public function showbilling($locale, $id)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing 2 params in your route but accepting only 1 in the controller.  Add locale.

`public function showbilling($locale, $id)`